# Continuity of $f_{xy}$ and existence of $f_{yx}$ implies continuity of $f_{yx}$? Partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. Is the following statement true? If:

1. $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial y \partial x}$ is continuous at a point $A$ and
2. $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}$ exists at $A$

Then $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x \partial y}$ is continuous at $A$.

If this is false, does requiring that $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x \partial y}$ must exist at $A$ make it true?

I got into an argument with my college calculus teacher - it feels completely false to me, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: For the partial derivatives, LaTeX (and MathJax) have a special delta `\partial` ($\partial$) to use instead of `\delta` ($\delta$).

Comment: In the title you write “existence of $f_{yx}$” but in the question there's just $\partial f/\partial y$. Which one should it be?

Comment: @HansLundmark My question is about both the stronger claim and the weaker claim. It starts only with $f_y$, but then says "If this is false, does requiring that $f_{yx}$ exist at $A$ make it true?"

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: This could be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291919/assumptions-for-a-variation-of-clairauts-theorem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98514/existence-of-mixed-partials-in-clairauts-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this result is true.

It is for example stated as Theorem 9.41 (page 235-236) in the book

> Walter Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (1976), International Series in Pure & Applied Mathematics, McGraw-Hill, ISBN 0-07-054235-X.
>
> **Theorem 9.41:** If $\partial_x f$, $\partial_{yx} f$ and $\partial_y f$ exist on some neighborhood of $A$ and $\partial_{yx} f$ is continuous at $A$, then $\partial_{xy} f$ exists at $A$, is continuous at $A$ and $\partial_{xy} f = \partial_{yx} f$.

Comment: The result I stated includes the assumption that $\partial_y f$ exists on a neighborhood of $A$ (not only at $A$), which is not stated in your question, but it seems reasonable to assume this if you are going to differentiate $\partial_y f$.