# Regarding recommendations for calculus books

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to learn calculus by myself, I searched a lot on internet as well as math stack exchange for suggestions for best calculus books, I know a lot of famous books like Stewart Thomas but I do not like the way it is presented. I want to learn rigorous mathematics from books like Apostol Spivak Courhant Serge-Lang,  but I am not sure if I can take them, the level of proofs and logic they need, I am afraid if I buy them and not able to solve because  high advanced level they are, some motivations is needed and also guide me if I need some more books as prerequisite to understand Apostol Spivak Courhant

I am reading books like how to solve it by George Polya, if you can suggest some books which refine logic and thinking please suggest me.

I am also someone who enjoys mathematics but not want to learn just basics.
its more like dream if I one day able to read and understand books like real analysis by Walter Rudin

THANK YOU

Comment: Learning calculus is a worthy pursuit. Now what can we do to get you to capitalize some of those 'i's?

Comment: not good in english, sorry

Comment: @SHIBA [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514906), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44522) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43290) are *some* examples. This kind of question has been asked many times especially in the past, I recommend you browse around some related posts

Comment: Also to help you properly we should have a better idea of "what level you're at". You mentioned Courant's book - I can tell you that this book is much more geared towards real analysis than just calculus